# Why was Tammy from Ocean's 8 not investigated?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-8

When James Corden's character investigates the stolen necklace, why was Tammy not questioned? Especially since she's the one who "pulled it from the water".

Comment: Imo most of the post heist part of Oceans 8 relies on James Corden's character SUPER not caring if he actually got the guilty party--it's obviously Debbie, but they seem to be friends.

Comment: I thought for sure they'd make a big deal about the magnetic clasp. From what we were shown, there's no way it could have simply fallen off, so why did the security accept that it did so quickly? The first suspect would've been the one to 'find' it in the water.

Answer (score 3):

As an experienced investigator, John Frazier (Corden) was quick to identify his real lead. It is true that he probably should have started with Tammy as you say, coz after all she is the one who pulled it out of the water. But he realizes that Tammy is not the big fish.

He already has his own doubts and his eyes on Debbie. He possibly even knows that Tammy is a known associate of Debbie and Lou's. Given this, why would he waste his time on Tammy only for her to deny any involvement in this. The crew certainly would have prepared for any initial investigation against her. That is why you see the one with the cleanest background infiltrate Vogue. Tangling with her would have cost Frazier precious time. Time he wanted to spend getting back the necklace.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kitkat already said, John Frazier is really not caring about the "whodunnit" part, he just want to get the necklace.

At least he says so in the diner scene:

[image]